# Ubuntu WSL2 disconnect both WSL2 and Windows host from the Internet

Tags: linux, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-server

My Ubuntu distro on WSL2 continues to disconnect both Ubuntu and Windows host from the Internet.

Everything has been working as I expected. I do `ping google.com` on both Ubuntu WSL2 and Windows. The connectivity still working.

**My WSL1 distros are still working. Seems like it is the bug in WSL2 kernel and WSL2 network configuration?**

### Computer Information

OS Host: Windows 10 Pro 22H2

OS WSL: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (WSL2)

WSL version: 5.10.102.1

Virtualization:

- Hyper-V features off
- WSL feature on

### Before start the `sudo apt install`

On Windows:

```
Pinging google.com [142.250.4.100] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 142.250.4.100: bytes=32 time=59ms TTL=54
Reply from 142.250.4.100: bytes=32 time=65ms TTL=54
Reply from 142.250.4.100: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=54
Reply from 142.250.4.100: bytes=32 time=75ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 142.250.4.100:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 48ms, Maximum = 75ms, Average = 61ms
```

On Ubuntu (WSL2):

```
PING google.com (142.250.4.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=1 ttl=105 time=410 ms
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=2 ttl=105 time=186 ms
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=3 ttl=105 time=134 ms
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=4 ttl=105 time=156 ms
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=5 ttl=105 time=142 ms
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=6 ttl=105 time=82.2 ms
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=7 ttl=105 time=93.2 ms
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=8 ttl=105 time=61.3 ms
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=9 ttl=105 time=68.9 ms
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=10 ttl=105 time=66.4 ms
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=11 ttl=105 time=105 ms
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=12 ttl=105 time=305 ms
64 bytes from sm-in-f113.1e100.net (142.250.4.113): icmp_seq=13 ttl=105 time=62.5 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 13 received, 0% packet loss, time 12020ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 61.298/144.075/409.572/100.602 ms
```

### After start the `sudo apt install`

However, when I tried `sudo apt install -y pciutils libvulkan1 build-essential`, it started to disconnect me from the Internet - on both Windows and Ubuntu WSL2. This really affects me while doing my projects:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libllvm15 amd64 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Connection timed out [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 mesa-vulkan-drivers amd64 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-15/libllvm15_15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  Connection timed out [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa-vulkan-drivers_22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1%7e22.04.1_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

The same thing also happens on Windows host:

```
Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

### Solving - None of them actually work

1. Disable IPv6 from [this help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248825/how-can-i-fix-internet-connection-issues-on-wsl2). Actually, it only affects IPv6, while I had seen that the broken IP was IPv4
2. Edit the `/etc/wsl.conf` and `/etc/resolv.conf`. That doesn't mean anything.

   - `/etc/resolv.conf` only affects how it resolve the DNS, but still - **IT EVEN CANNOT REACH THE DNS SERVER, HOW CAN IT RESOLVE THE DOMAIN NAME.**
   - `/etc/wsl.conf`: I tried these conditions:

     - `generateResolvConf = true` & `generateHosts = false`: It still can ping, but cannot do anything else after I do the `sudo apt install`
     - `generateResolvConf = false` & `generateHosts = true`: It still can ping, but cannot do anything else after I do the `sudo apt install`
     - `generateResolvConf = false` & `generateHosts = false`: Totally disconnect WSL2 from the Internet, while the Windows is still remain.
     - `generateResolvConf = true` & `generateHosts = false`: Default doesn't work
3. [Disconnect `eth0`](https://superuser.com/questions/1746203/how-to-disable-internet-connection-in-wsl2) is totally useless
4. Unblock from Symantec Endpoint Protection - I have never use SEP, only large computers in my company use it.
5. Swap file: No swap file is configured.
6. Debugging is turned off. I may need to use it to figure out the kernel activities.

Comment: Good news: Windows 11 fixed all the problems I had. Seems like Windows 10 was having problems with network bridge.